# Micronaut Unable to implement Repository method: Repository.update(Object entity). No possible implementations found

Tags: java, maven, micronaut, micronaut-data

**Here's my stack:**
- Micronaut 1.3.2
- Java 8
- Eclipse STS 4

**Pom.xml excerpt:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<path>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
</path>
```

My Repository:

```
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<UsuarioModel, Long> { }
```

My Service:

```
private UsuarioDTO atualizar(UsuarioDTO usuario) {
      UsuarioModel modelo = new UsuarioModel();
      modelo.setIdade(usuario.idade);
      modelo.setNick(usuario.nick);
      modelo.setNome(usuario.nome);
      modelo.setPassword(usuario.password);
      this.usuarioRepository.update(modelo);
      return usuario;
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-chatroom
  server: 
    cors:
      enabled: true
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: H2
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
        packages: 'com.cr.model'
```

When I'm running Install maven command on my Micronaut project I get the error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project micronaut-chatroom: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Unable to implement Repository method: UsuarioRepository.update(Object entity). No possible implementations found.

Has someone been through it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's my UsuarioModel class

```
@Entity(name = "Usuario")
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class UsuarioModel implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7468837154917949190L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String nick;
    private String idade;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany
    private List<MensagemModel> mensagens;

    //Getter/Setters ommited

}
```

And also my MensagemModel class:

```
@Entity(name = "Mensagem")
@Table(name = "mensagem")
public class MensagemModel implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7634793331670289187L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime data;
    private String conteudo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id")
    private UsuarioModel usuario;
    //Getter/Setter ommited
}
```

Comment: Please include your `Usuario` class.

Comment: Show us also `UsuarioModel` class. It is important to be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hmm entity is OK. This exception is often caused by missing `@Entity` annotation. But not in this case. Can you try to remove `jpa.default.entity-scan` definition from _application.yml_?

Comment: Thanks for the support!
I've tried without It but got the same error thought :/

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT:

There are 2 possible sources for the `@Id` decorator in micronaut:

- the "native" annotation package: `io.micronaut.data.annotation`
- the jpa persistance package available as: `jakarta.persistence-api` dependency in maven

As you are decorating the class with `@Entity` I suppose you are using the latter set of decorators. or at least a mix of the 2 sources.

As basic debug step you could try removing any reference to javax.persistance and use native only decorators. So, as instance, do not use `@Entity` but rather `@MappedEntity` and so on.

simply comment out any import from `javax.persistence.*` and try with native `io.micronaut.data.annotation*`.

this would make clearer - I hope- if the issue lies in some twist of the annotation process.

#### OLD RUBBISH HAS BEEN DELETED - was Kotlin related

Comment: Sorry for the late response,
First of all, thanks!
Could you, please, explain to me which package this @field comes from?

Comment: Sorry, my very bad: that is a kotlin decorator! I was forgetting that I was on kotlin and not java. I've anyway edited my answer. please look at the edit section.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The fix to the problem was to create getters and setters for the fields in the model.